# std::stoi results in segfault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, buildroot

I have the following test program:

```
#include <string>
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    try {
        return std::stoi("3000127232");
    }
    catch (...) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

When I compile this on ubuntu with C++11 and run the code I get a return value of 0. This is what I expect because the value in the string is out of range.

But when I compile it for a rasperry-buildroot 18.11 I can run the program on rasperry, but I get a segfault. This I don't expect.

Is there another solution to convert strings to ints (without segfaults when out of range), or does anyone have another idea?

Comment: Can you debug your program and see where is segfaults?

Comment: Do you get segfault on rasperry with some in range value like `0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::stoi` is specified to throw an exception if the value is out of range. If the implementation fails to do that, then it doesn't conform to the standard. This may be a compiler bug.

If for example you target a system that doesn't support exceptions or is for some other reason non-conformant, there are other ways to convert a string to an integer that don't use exceptions, such as `std::strtol`.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check size of int on your raspberry, it probably gets out of range.

Comment: Raspi runs on ARM, so probably it has 32-bit int